How to configure Qt Creator for cross-compiling
I am trying to run Qt6 demo examples on my RPi 3B running Yocto. The problem appears when I try to configure the cross-compilers in Qt Creator "Remote Linux Device".
The build machine is x86-64, running Ubuntu 24.04. I use latest free Qt 6.8.0 and latest Yocto 5.0.3 Scarthgap.
As cross-compilers, I use the ones built as a part of the Yocto SDK build for Raspberry Pi 3 (32 bit), but when I configure Qt Creator with them, I receive an error message:

Compiler GCC cannot produce code for the Qt version (Qt 6.8.0)

As displayed in this screenshot:

The trials to configure with ARM cross-compilers from Ubuntu distribution or ARM website are ending with the similar kind of error messages.
What's causing this problem?

Could it be because your version of Qt looks like it was built for 64bit but you're trying to use a 32 bit compiler?

@JarMan, I worry this unfortunately will not be the case as the ARM cross-compilers I tried also, were 64bit

After receiving @JarMan's comment, I verified the Qt and I found that my Qt pointed to the build host Qt installation. After I manually pointed to the cross-compiled Qt from the Yocto SDK, the error disappeared.
